# Find the area of triangle $DEF$ given that...

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rectangles

> Points $E$ and $F$ are on sides $AB$ and $BC$ of rectangle $ABCD$ so that: $S_{ADE}=5,S_{CDF}=3,S_{BEF}=8$.Calculate the area of triangle $DEF$($S_{DEF}$)

I just could write a relation between areas of all triangles taking into account length and width of rectangle,but nothing more...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
10 &=& AE.AD\\
6  &=& DC.FC\\
16 &=& BE.BF=(DC-AE)(AD-FC)
\end{eqnarray}
then from third 
$$16 = (DC-\frac{10}{AD})(AD-\frac{6}{CD})$$
with $AD=x$ and $CD=y$ we get
$$(xy)^2-32(xy)+60=0$$
then two answers obtain
$$S_1=\frac12xy=1$$
$$S_2=\frac12xy=15$$

Comment: Your answer is wrong,but your method is quite right.I used your method to get 14 as the answer: $S_{DEF}=14$